# Introducing 'tensor product' constraint into linear programs

Tags: linear-programming, tensor-products

I have a problem that can nicely be formatted as a linear program. However, I wish to add a constraint to the linear program such that the output vector $v_{n}$ be expressible as a tensor product of any two arbitrary vectors $a_{m_1}$ and $b_{m_2}$ (where $ m_1m_2 = n$). Is there any way to introduce such constraints into the linear programming formulation?

Comment: The constraint $v=a\otimes b$ isn't linear, because the sum of two tensor products needn't be a tensor product. So if there is a solution it will be outside the domain of "linear programming".

Comment: @OscarCunningham I was thinking about using something like ADMM to solve the problem, i.e convert the optimization problem from a single vector (and a constraint - that it is expressible as a tensor product (which as you rightly pointed out, is not linear)) problem to that of the two vectors (i.e. $a_{m_1}$ and $a_{m_2}$ and in every optimization, independently update the two vectors. This would be linear because in each of the two updates per iteration, either $a_{m_1}$ or $a_{m_2}$ would be constant.